# Changing CSS from jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors, children

I am trying to change the CSS of a div through jQuery. Below is the jQuery code.

```
$(".endPollingButton").click(function () {
    var endPollingCode = $(this).attr("value");
    var correctAnswer = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
    for(LCV=1;LCV<=5;LCV++) {
        if(LCV == correctAnswer) {
            $("#"+endPollingCode).children(".Bars_"+LCV).css("background-color","green");
            alert("check");
        } else {  
            $("#"+endPollingCode).children(".Bars_"+LCV).css("background-color","red");
            alert("check");
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the html code:

```
for($LCV = 1; $LCV <= $rowCount; $LCV++) {
                    echo "<div class='graphBlock' id='".$questionCode[$LCV]."' value=''>";
                    echo "<div id='questionCodeBar'>Quiz Code: ".$questionCode[$LCV]."</div>";
                    echo "<div id='questionTitleBar'>".$questionName[$LCV]."</div>";
                    echo "<span class='barsInfo' id='barsInfo1".$LCV."'></span><div class='bars_1' id='bars1".$LCV."' style='width:;'></div>";
                    echo "<span class='barsInfo' id='barsInfo2".$LCV."'></span><div class='bars_2' id='bars2".$LCV."' style='width:;'></div>";
                    echo "<span class='barsInfo' id='barsInfo3".$LCV."'></span><div class='bars_3' id='bars3".$LCV."' style='width:;'></div>";
                    echo "<span class='barsInfo' id='barsInfo4".$LCV."'></span><div class='bars_4' id='bars4".$LCV."' style='width:;'></div>";
                    echo "<span class='barsInfo' id='barsInfo5".$LCV."'></span><div class='bars_5' id='bars5".$LCV."' style='width:;'></div>";
                    echo "<button class='endPollingButton' id='".$correctAnswer[$LCV]."' value='".$questionCode[$LCV]."' >End Polling</button>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
```

The code above is not working. I am unsure whether there is any syntax error. Both of the check alerts are working. If you need any more code like the HTML to which this is linked, please let me know and I would be happy to provide it. Please help if you can. Thanks.

Pleaseee help.......

Comment: there is a dot in the 2nd css call `"background-color"."red"` and your if statement should test with comparasion operator `==`, not assignment operator `=`

Comment: Have you checked the error console in Firebug?

Comment: Do polls really have a correct answer? :)

Comment: @f00bar I have changed those errors but even then the background color of the div is not changing. Btw, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Guido what is Firebug? Thanks!

Comment: Firebug is a debugging tool for firefox that will let you see any javascript errors (in addition to other things)

Comment: When I press the button there is no change in Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. You guys answered correctly based on the information I gave you. Turns out the class that I was referring to, ".Bars_"+LCV, should have been, ".bars_"+LCV. Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

looks like a single / double / triple equals typo.

```
if(LCV = correctAnswer) {
```

should probably be

```
if(LCV === correctAnswer) {
```

also, there is a dot in your second css call where there should be a comma.

You might also consider adding a radix to your `parseInt` call in case the string it's parsing starts with a `0` or some other unfortunate character :)

Radix is what base you want to parse the integer as. for example, the string "101" could be read as "one hundred and one" base 10, or it could be interpreted as a binary number meaning "nine". `parseInt` defaults to base 10 unless the string you give it starts with a `0` or `0x`. check out the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

EDIT:

I think it is a logic problem rather than a syntax problem. Is the correct answer always a number in [1,2,3,4,5]? you should also change the message that gets alerted in your if/else blocks so you can tell which one is being executed.

Comment: You are right, I changed the = to == and the . was a typing error in StackOverflow it was correct in my code. Could you please explain what that radix means? I've seen it before and I am still unsure as to what it does or represents. Thanks!

Comment: So to do a base 10 representation, I would have to change the line to var correctAnswer = parseInt($(this).attr("id"),10);?

Comment: to ensure that it is base 10 regardless of the input string, yes.

Comment: I inserted the line change as in the comment above but it still does not work....

Comment: Yes the correct answer is always a number in between 1 and 5. Also I tried using different alerts in the if statements to see which if statement is being executed and the result was as expected, the correct if statements are executed. I think the problem is with the actual css change line. I am going to paste the HTML linked to this jQuery because I think that is where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean if(LCV == correctAnswer)  ? :)

Comment: You are right, I fixed that error however still the background color of the div is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

also correct LCV = correctAnswer
instead of using assignment operator use "==" a comparison opperator

Answer (score -1):

there is syntax error in your function

correct
         $("#"+endPollingCode).children(".Bars_"+LCV).css("background-color"."red");

with

```
     $("#"+endPollingCode).children(".Bars_"+LCV).css("background-color","red");
```